# child pid xxxxx exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: apache

My website keeps crashing and the hosting company have informed that the error sits with an 'Apache'.

*Essentially there's loads of lines saying:
child pid xxxxx exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
At the time of the crash in the apache error log.*

Can anyone help with this and advise on a fix / explanation.

Much appreciated

Comment: Sadly a segmentation fault can be caused by a whole bunch of things, normally extensions. Are you using mod_php by any chance?

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I will have to check with my dev team but I think we are.

Comment: We've built the site in wordpress (3.8.1)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your PHP-FPM and PHP versions match. Make sure there is a (correct) PHP-FPM configuration corresponding to your PHP and PHP-FPM version, respectively.

PHP-FPM (config in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm`) and PHP versions may have gotten out of sync while updating. Updated PHP (`/etc/php/7.3/`) may cause apache child segfaults because of missing PHP-FPM configuration in `/etc/php/7.3/`.

See also [“[notice] child pid XXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11)” in apache error.log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54841259/10050838) .